# Incorrect syntax near ']'.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error, ssms

I have done some debugging on my sql and I cant figure out the maddening error I am getting I have narrowed it down to a couple of lines which I cant see what the problem is, please someone give me some assistance.

I get this error

I am here2
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near
 ']'.
I am here3

```
 Print 'I am here2'
                        SET IDENTITY_INSERT c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany ON
                        declare @cols2 varchar(max)
                        select @cols2 = (Select Stuff((Select '],[' + C.COLUMN_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION For Xml Path('')), 1, 2, '') As Columns From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = @tablename)
                        EXEC('INSERT INTO [' + @Destination_Database_Name + '].[dbo].[' + @tablename + '] (' + @cols2 + ']' + ') SELECT ' + @cols2 + ']' + ' FROM [' + @Source_Database_Name + '].[dbo].[' + @tablename + ']');
                         Print 'I am here3'
```

Comment: Rather than just blindly `EXEC`ing whatever SQL you're producing, you could change it to a `PRINT` instead and *see* what SQL you're attempting to run. That will tend to be a lot quicker than making a tweak, running your code, getting an error, posting to SO, and then hoping someone can diagnose the issue without seeing the SQL. Even if you can't solve it yourself, being able to *show* us what SQL you're generating should make the feedback much quicker.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing an opening square bracket here:

```
... ') SELECT ' + @cols2 + ']' + ' FROM ...
```

Furthermore I would recommend you switch to using [the `QuoteName()` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) instead:

```
... ') SELECT ' + QuoteName(@cols2) + ' FROM...
```

Comment: How would my code look with the opening square bracket Im unsure where it could go

Comment: I recommend not using them and instead switching to the QuoteName() function. I've already pointed you in the right direction but I'm not putting the answer on a plate for you. You won't learn without trying!

Comment: This is almost certainly wrong because `@cols2` has been created to contain *multiple* column names, and looks something like `[columnA],[columnB],[columnC` (check the `FOR XML` on the line above). Using `QuoteName` would attempt to treat that as the name of a single column.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well spotted. Just another reason to loathe dynamic SQL ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing about 3 opening brackets  as far as i can tell at

```
select @cols2 = (Select Stuff((Select '],[
```

and

```
 (' + @cols2 + ']' // -> either [' + @cols2 + ']' or (' + @cols2 + ')'
```

and

```
 + ') SELECT ' + @cols2 + ']'  -- -> either ') SELECT [' + @cols2 + ']'  or ') SELECT (' + @cols2 + ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @cols2 nvarchar(max)
select @cols2 = (Select Stuff((Select ',[' + C.COLUMN_NAME  + ']'
                From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C 
                Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA 
                And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
                Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION For Xml Path('')), 1, 1, '') As Columns 
                From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T 
                WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = @tablename)
```

**Edit**

```
DECLARE @Destination_Database_Name NVARCHAR(128) = 'Trg_DataBaseName'
DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(128) = 'AgressoIFCGLItems'
DECLARE   @Source_Database_Name NVARCHAR(128) = 'Configsandpit'

Print 'I am here2'

--SET IDENTITY_INSERT c365online_script1.dbo.tCompany ON
declare @cols2 varchar(max)
select @cols2 = (Select Stuff((Select  ',' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME)  [text()]
                From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C 
                Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA 
                And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME 
                Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION For Xml Path('')), 1, 1, '') As Columns 
                From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T 
                WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = @tablename)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@Destination_Database_Name) + '.[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + ' (' + @cols2 +   ') SELECT ' + @cols2  + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Source_Database_Name) + '.[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + '';

EXECUTE sp_Executesql @sql
```

Your need to change you @Sql Statement after you have used QOUTENAME function as it adds the square backets for you, you do not need to concatinate square barckets in your Sql statement.

**Result**

```
INSERT INTO [Trg_DataBaseName].[dbo].[TableName] ([Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4],[Col5]) SELECT [Col1],[Col2],[Col3],[Col4],[Col5] FROM [Src_Database].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Comment: Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 56
Could not find stored procedure ''.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ']'.
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 59
Could not find stored procedure 'c365online_script1'.

Comment: Your need to change you @Sql Statement after you have used QOUTENAME function as it adds the square backets for you, you do not need to concatinate square barckets in your Sql statement.